# Parsing JSON returns cryptic error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have some JSON (https://gist.github.com/tekknolagi/8526671) that I am requesting for a list of my blog posts.

I got some funky errors in the console:
[image]

And also in JSONLint:
[image]

I cannot figure out what's wrong. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: '/posts.json',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
//      data = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
        console.log(data);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        var parsed = data;
        var names = []
        for (var post in parsed) names.push(post.title);
        console.log(names);
        $('#page_holder').pagify({ 
        pages: data,
        default: null
        });
    },
    fail: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    });
});
```

And it always fails on the parse. This has been killing me for weeks.

Comment: @TravisJ seems escaped...

Comment: How did you get such "JSON" ? You should use a library to build JSON.

Comment: @dystroy I am generating it with Liquid, but their own `json` or `jsonify` filter does not work... for some reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line that throws the error has this inside the string:

```
Type \&quot;help\&quot;, \&quot;copyright\&quot;, \&quot;credits\&quot; or \&quot;license\&quot;
```

`\&` is not a valid escape sequence in JSON strings values:

[image]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>

---

"Proof":

```
["\&foo"]
```

results in the same error

---

Since I don't know how the `\` got there in the first place, it's not really possible to provide a solution. But to make the JSON valid, you have to remove those (or double them as Pointy pointed out (no pun intended)) (before you generate the JSON). A proper JSON library should actually take care of escaping the `\` correctly.

Comment: It also has some tab characters in there, and those aren't allowed either. (*edit* maybe)

Comment: The `\&` things can be made JSON-safe by doubling the \, right?

Comment: @Pointy: Yes and which tabs are you talking about? If I just remove the ``\`` before the `&`, the JSON is valid.

Comment: Hmm when I search through that raw string, there are some tab characters in it. The JSON spec is not very clear about what it means by "control characters" however, so maybe tab (0x0009) characters are allowed.